# Return the last added picture from a picture folder using SQL

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a web app linked to an access database. The web app takes pictures and stores them in a folder. I am trying to link the record to the file by trying to retrieve the last picture added to a picture folder.

Each picture is given the date and time as the filename e.g. `20150615105326.jpg`.
So I basically need to retrieve the `MAX(filename)`, but have no idea how.

I'm working on an SQL query:

```
`Dim newestpic, SQL1
newestpic = ew_execute(select newest picture in folder - this is where I need help)
SQL1 = ("UPDATE [Visitors] SET [Image] = "http://localhost/photos/" & newestpic & " WHERE thisID = thatID");")
Call ew_Execute(SQL1)`
```

I just need help setting the newestpic. I have researched for hours but got nowhere, please help.

@Bond again.
`' Row Updated event
    Sub Row_Updated(rsold, rsnew)
    server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim newestpic, SQL1

newestpic = .Exec("%comspec% /c dir ""C:\Users\ashwortm\Desktop\testcam1\Photos"" /a-d /b /o-d *.jpg").StdOut.ReadLine
SQL1 = ("UPDATE [Visitors] SET [visname] = "http://localhost/photos/" & newestpic & "" WHERE [Table1].[ID] = 1;")

Call ew_Execute(SQL1)

End Sub`

OK with @Bond 's help and researching so far I have...
`' Row Updated event
    Sub Row_Updated(rsold, rsnew)
    Dim oShell, SQL1
    set oshell=server.createobject("WScript.Shell")

    oshell.run "cmd.exe /c dir ""C:\Users\ashwortm\Desktop\testcam1\Photos"" /a-d /b /o-d *.jpg".StdOut.ReadLine
SQL1 = ("UPDATE [Visitors] SET [visname] = "http://localhost/photos/" & oShell & "" WHERE [Table1].[ID] = 1;") 
set oShell=nothing

Call ew_Execute(SQL1`

This still does not work but I can feel I'm getting closer. Can anyone spot any mistakes in the above code?

Comment: So, if I'm reading this right, you're trying to parse the file names in a directory using SQL?  If so, you're going to have a bad time...

Comment: Hi Siyual, I'm just trying to retrieve the filename with the highest value from a directory. Or retrieve the newest file in the directory. Same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate all files by using a `FileSystemObject`, which is probably what most VBScripters would do.

But if you don't mind the flash of a command prompt, put the trusty `dir` command to work for you.

```
Set oShell = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Sorted by filename (what you requested)...
newestpic = oShell.Exec("%comspec% /c dir ""c:\my folder\*.jpg"" /a-d /b /on").StdOut.ReadLine

' Or, sorted by date (may work even better for you)...
newestpic = oShell.Exec("%comspec% /c dir ""c:\my folder\*.jpg"" /a-d /b /o-d").StdOut.ReadLine
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Will give this a try now and let you know. Do I need to add the `with Createobject and End With` ?

Comment: Well, you need a[`WshShell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99(v=vs.84).aspx) object to run the [`Exec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a(v=vs.84).aspx) function. If you already have one in your code, then no.

Comment: Hi @Bond, it did not seem to work, the page stopped loading my full code has been added to original question. Have not used `with` before hope I've put it in the right place. I added the code to the original question for better viewing.

Comment: Is this an ASP page? If so, use `Server.CreateObject` instead.

Comment: @ Bond. Yes it is sorry I should have mentioned. Nood trying to learn fast. Do I get rid of the `with` and `end with`? or do I just replace `Exec` with `Server.CreateObject`. To be honest im unsure where to put `server.createobject` sorry to be a pain. Your help is saving my neck. Much appreciated.

Comment: I've edited the answer. It sounds like this is all pretty new to you so I would suggest picking up some basic VBS and ASP, including the `WshShell` and `FileSystemObject`, and `CreateObject` vs `Server.CreateObject`, among other things. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx7b3k7y(v=vs.84).aspx) should help you get started.